# ViewModel modification makes existing list.phtml break

Tags: template, category-products, view, category-view, viewmodel

I recently made a modification to `catalog-category-view.xml` and overrode `category.products.list`.
It seemed to work at the time, I had badges displaying on a rendered page.

Now the template file errors because `$pos` (line 42 in src file) returns null.
I have not changed anything about the template file except for the injection of a small php if statement and an additional docblock. Here is the error:

```
2021/01/08 17:15:14 [error] 1415#1415: *1053 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, null given in /var/www/html/magento-new/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml:97
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento-new/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml(97): strpos(NULL, 'grid-actions')
#1 /var/www/html/magento-new/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/html/m...')
#2 /var/www/html/magento-new/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor), '/var/www/html/m...', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/magento-new/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callParent('render', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/magento-new/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: dev.magento.com, request: "GET /gear/fitness-equipment.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host: "dev.magento.com", referrer: "http://dev.magento.com/gear.html"
```

`app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_Module/assets/css/styles.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list" template="Vendor_Module::product/list.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\ViewModel\ProductList</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Relevant snippet from `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`:

```
            <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) :?>
            <li class="item product product-item">
                <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-<?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?>">
                    <?php
                    $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $imageDisplayArea);
                    if ($pos != null) {
                        $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                            . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
                    }
                    $productBadgeId = $_product->getData('product_badge');
                    ?>
                    <?php if($productBadgeId): ?>
                    <img
                        src=<?= $block->getViewModel()->getBadgeImage($productBadgeId) ?>
                        class="product-item-badge"
                        alt=<?= $block->getViewModel()->getBadgeImageAlt($productBadgeId)?>
                    />
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php // Product Image ?>
```

My only additions: `$productBadgeId` and the `<?php if($productBadgeId)?>` if statement

`app/code/Vendor/Module/ViewModel/ProductList.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package      Vendor_Module
 * @author       Scott Anderson <scott.anderson@Vendor.com>
 * @copyright    Copyright (c) 2020 Vendor, Inc (http://Vendor.com)
 * @license      http://opensource.org/licenses/OSL-3.0 The Open Software License 3.0 (OSL-3.0)
 */

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\ViewModel;

use Exception;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Model\BadgeRepository;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Badge;

/**
 * Class ProductList
 * @package Vendor\Module\ViewModel
 */
class ProductList implements ArgumentInterface
{
    /**
     * @var BadgeRepository
     */
    protected $badgeRepository;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @param BadgeRepository       $badgeRepository
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        BadgeRepository $badgeRepository,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->badgeRepository = $badgeRepository;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param int|null $badgeId
     *
     * @return Badge|string|null
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getBadgeImage(int $badgeId = null)
    {
        if ($badgeId) {
            $badge = $this->badgeRepository->get($badgeId);

            if ($badge) {
                $mediaUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
                return $mediaUrl . $badge->getImage();
            }
        }

        return $badgeId;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $badgeId
     *
     * @return mixed
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function getBadgeImageAlt(int $badgeId)
    {
        $badge = $this->badgeRepository->get($badgeId);
        return $badge->getName();
    }
}
```

If anyone wants other files such as `di.xml` please let me know - I am not sure what else could be relevant.

I was also making a cron job in a different module which may have caused inconsistencies in the db, but I don't really know how to check this. I wonder if my viewModel needs to extend something, but I can't see anything in module-catalog

Comment: Please provide the code of `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`  ? Full code?

Comment: @AmitBera I solved this, so not necessary - I added `declare(strict_types=1);` at the top and apparently for template files this is a bad idea, and resulted in the errors shown. Anyways the full code of this file is otherwise copy-paste from module-catalog

Comment: Please post the answer at here. It will help pther people

Answer (score 0):

This string of errors were caused by a simple mistake, when pushing to code review I added `declare(strict_types=1)` at the top of my `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml` file.

This is not necessary in M2 template files as far as I am aware (although for PSR compliance it is advised to use it at the top of your PHP class files [below the docblock]). A summary of the amendment:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/**
 * @package      Vendor_Module
 * @author       Some Guy <some.guy@Vendor.com>
 * @copyright    Copyright (c) 2020 Vendor, Inc (http://Vendor.com)
 * @license      http://opensource.org/licenses/OSL-3.0 The Open Software License 3.0 (OSL-3.0)
 */

declare(strict_types=1); \\ remove this!

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
```